# tensorflow: check if a scalar boolean tensor is True

Tags: python, tensorflow, boolean-operations

I want to control the execution of a function using a placeholder, but keep getting an error "Using a tf.Tensor as a Python bool is not allowed". Here is the code that produces this error:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def foo(c):
  if c:
    print('This is true')
    #heavy code here
    return 10
  else:
    print('This is false')
    #different code here
    return 0

a = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)  #placeholder for a single boolean value
b = foo(a)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
res = sess.run(b, feed_dict = {a: True})
sess.close()
```

I changed `if c` to `if c is not None` without luck. How can I control `foo` by turning on and off the placeholder `a` then?

Update: as @nessuno and @nemo point out, we must use `tf.cond` instead of `if..else`. The answer to my question is to re-design my function like this:

```
import tensorflow as tf
def foo(c):
  return tf.cond(c, func1, func2)

a = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)  #placeholder for a single boolean value
b = foo(a)
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
res = sess.run(b, feed_dict = {a: True})
sess.close()
```

Comment: About 5 years old, and not good for TF2.x

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have to use [`tf.cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/api_docs/python/tf/cond) to define a conditional operation within the graph and change, thus, the flow of the tensors.

```
import tensorflow as tf

a = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)  #placeholder for a single boolean value
b = tf.cond(tf.equal(a, tf.constant(True)), lambda: tf.constant(10), lambda: tf.constant(0))
sess = tf.InteractiveSession()
res = sess.run(b, feed_dict = {a: True})
sess.close()
print(res)
```

> 10

Comment: the `foo` function is very complicated in practice. I just want to change some operations in that function by turning `a` on/off. How can I keep the `foo` function? I suspect the problem is from either `{a: True}` or `if c:`

Comment: You just have to define the two different functions to execute when the condition is evaluated. The only limitation is that both must return the same number and type of values. Thus, instead of lambdas you can define you own functions and use them

Answer (score 1):

The actual execution is not done in Python but in the TensorFlow backend which you supply with the computation graph it is supposed to execute. This means that every condition and flow control you want to apply has to be formulated as a node in the computation graph.

For `if` conditions there is the [`cond`](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.11/api_docs/python/control_flow_ops/control_flow_operations#cond) operation:

```
b = tf.cond(c, 
           lambda: tf.constant(10), 
           lambda: tf.constant(0))
```

Answer (score 0):

A simpler way to tackle it:

```
In [50]: a = tf.placeholder(tf.bool)                                                                                                                                                                                 

In [51]: is_true = tf.count_nonzero([a])                                                                                                                                                                             

In [52]: sess.run(is_true, {a: True})                                                                                                                                                                                
Out[52]: 1

In [53]: sess.run(is_true, {a: False})
Out[53]: 0
```