# How do I convert C++ tensorflow code to python?

Tags: python, c++, tensorflow

I have a few lines of sensorflow code in C++ that I need to understand and convert to Python:

```
tensorflow::Tensor phaseTrain(tensorflow::DT_BOOL,tensorflow::TensorShape());
phaseTrain.scalar<bool>()() = false;
```

How can I best translate this to Python?

Comment: the code is to set bool value as false on the tensor phaseTrain. see this link I think it will help you https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43263933/tensorflow-check-if-a-scalar-boolean-tensor-is-true
https://www.programcreek.com/python/example/90386/tensorflow.bool